# Ignore Where Clause in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, where-clause

I want to query a table, however I want to ignore WHERE clause if it's equal a certain value : Here is my Code :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE seen :seen")
public abstract List<content> getContent(String seen);
```

I want to Ignore the where clause "seen" if it's equal to "False".

I tried with `seen = "seen"` , similar to `column = column`, but it didn't work , it does however work in Sqlite Database Browser.

Any help please

Comment: Any help please , I'm stuck with this one

Comment: Honestly, your question is not clear enough. Give some clear examples with inputs and desirable outputs and your chances to get answer will increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can understands you well, you need to get all the list except that equals to `False`, you can use the `!=` operator then

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE seen :seen AND seen != 'False'")
public abstract List<content> getContent(String seen);
```

Or you can pass `False` as a method parameter

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE seen :seen AND seen != :exclude")
public abstract List<content> getContent(String seen, String exclude);
```

But I am doubt that you mean you want to exclude the entire `WHERE` clause if the passed-in String equals to `False`, this can be done programmatically like below

**In Repository:**

```
public void getContent(String seen) {
    if (seen.equals("False"))
        mDao.getContent();
    else 
        mDao.getContent(seen);
}
```

And implement `getContent()` in Dao that has no arguments.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content")
public abstract List<content> getContent();
```

Note: you have to handle the list listener in the repository

Comment: Thank you , I did it programmatically as you explained and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these (your question could be interpreted in different ways):

**Option 1**. Ignore "WHERE"-clause if method's parameter `seen` is 'False'

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE seen =:seen OR :seen = 'False'")
public abstract List<content> getContent(String seen);
```

**Option2**. Ignore "WHERE"-clause for table's rows where field `seen` is 'False'

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE seen =:seen OR seen = 'False'")
public abstract List<content> getContent(String seen);
```